# How to distribute multiple environment variables among pods in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to spawn multiple containers of the same type, but each pod with a different (unique) environment variable (which is a private key).

How could I achieve this without introducing an additional service?

Comment: How is a service related to this?

Comment: Every replica of a Deployment is identical (up to an unpredictable pod name), so you either need to have multiple Deployments with a different Secret attached, or you need some sort of support service that can provide the keys.

Answer (score 0):

All the Pod replicas in the deployment will have the same environment variables and no unique value to identify a particular Pod. As mentioned by @David Maze creating multiple deployments with a different Secret attached is a better workaround.

Dividing single deployment into multiple sets of deployments and services would be the simplest solution. In each deployment you can have different [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables).

You describe a desired state in a Deployment, and the Deployment [Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/) changes the actual state to the desired state at a controlled rate. You can define Deployments to create new ReplicaSets, or to remove existing Deployments and adopt all their resources with new Deployments.